# Using Linq to parse XML data into an object in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datagridview, treeview

I have a fairly messy XML structure that I need to process and display to the end user. The XML structure holds information about Bars of metal and the Cuts to be made for each bar. The goal is to process this file, display to the user a list of the bars grouped by bar type. They can select a bar from this list where a gridview of some sort will display the cuts for that bar. They can then select a cut and the label information for that cut will be used to create a label with a barcode and some other information.

The structure of the XML can be seen below:

```
 <BODY>
<BAR>
  <BRAN>ALSPEC</BRAN>
  <SYST>Hunter 100mm Flush Glazed</SYST>
  <CODE>AS308</CODE>
  <DESC>Door Adaptor</DESC>
  <DICL>NOTRE DAME GLOSS</DICL>
  <DOCL>notre dame gloss p/coat</DOCL>
  <LEN> 6500</LEN>
  <STS>1</STS>
  <POS> 0</POS>
  <SVL> 0</SVL>
  <IVL> 0</IVL>
  <VROT> 0</VROT>
  <VU1S> 0</VU1S>
  <VU1D> 0</VU1D>
  <VU2S> 0</VU2S>
  <VU2D> 0</VU2D>
  <LENR> 201.3</LENR>
  <H> 26.5</H>
  <MLT> 1</MLT>
  <SCP> 0</SCP>
  <BRS> 0</BRS>
  <IFS> 0</IFS>
  <BS1L> 0</BS1L>
  <BS1R> 0</BS1R>
  <BS2L> 0</BS2L>
  <BS2R> 0</BS2R>
  <ENTH> 0</ENTH>
  <CUT>
    <NUM> 1</NUM>
    <TYPE></TYPE>
    <ANGL> 45</ANGL>
    <ANGR> 90</ANGR>
    <AB1> 90</AB1>
    <AB2> 90</AB2>
    <IL> 2064</IL>
    <OL> 2090.5</OL>
    <BCOD>000000231/5/44</BCOD>
    <CSNA></CSNA>
    <CSNU></CSNU>
    <TINA></TINA>
    <DESC>Jamb - Right</DESC>
    <STAT> 1</STAT>
    <LBL>Job# 760  Item# 5</LBL>
    <LBL>2090.5 mm</LBL>
    <LBL>W2-D8/T15</LBL>
    <LBL>Jamb - Right</LBL>
  </CUT>
  <CUT>
    <NUM> 1</NUM>
    <TYPE></TYPE>
    <ANGL> 45</ANGL>
    <ANGR> 90</ANGR>
    <AB1> 90</AB1>
    <AB2> 90</AB2>
    <IL> 2064</IL>
    <OL> 2090.5</OL>
    <BCOD>000000231/2/45</BCOD>
    <CSNA></CSNA>
    <CSNU></CSNU>
    <TINA></TINA>
    <DESC>Jamb - Right</DESC>
    <STAT> 1</STAT>
    <LBL>Job# 760  Item# 2</LBL>
    <LBL>2090.5 mm</LBL>
    <LBL>D8/T23</LBL>
    <LBL>Jamb - Right</LBL>
  </CUT>
  <CUT>
    <NUM> 1</NUM>
    <TYPE></TYPE>
    <ANGL> 90</ANGL>
    <ANGR> 45</ANGR>
    <AB1> 90</AB1>
    <AB2> 90</AB2>
    <IL> 2064</IL>
    <OL> 2090.5</OL>
    <BCOD>000000231/1/43</BCOD>
    <CSNA></CSNA>
    <CSNU></CSNU>
    <TINA></TINA>
    <DESC>Jamb - Left</DESC>
    <STAT> 1</STAT>
    <LBL>Job# 760  Item# 1</LBL>
    <LBL>2090.5 mm</LBL>
    <LBL>D8/T24</LBL>
    <LBL>Jamb - Left</LBL>
  </CUT>
</BAR>
 </BODY>
```

The result I am looking for is something like below i.e a tree view on the left and a datagridview on the right displaying all the cuts in the job, filtered by the tree view selection (only cuts from the selected tree view level down).

[GUI Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHYYG.png)

To achieve this I am trying to use LINQ to XML to parse the XML file into a class i have created:

```
public List<Bars> bars = new List<Bars>();

    public class Bars
    {
        public int Bar_id { set; get; }
        public string Brand { set; get; }
        public string System { set; get; }
        public string Code { set; get; }
        public string Description { set; get; }
        public string Length { set; get; }
        public string Status { set; get; }
        public string NumBars { set; get; }
        public List<Cuts> Cuts { set;  get; }
    }

    public class Cuts
    {
        public int Cut_id { set; get; }
        public int Bar_id { set; get; }
        public string AngleL { set; get; }
        public string AngleR { set; get; }
        public string LenInn { set; get; }
        public string LenOut { set; get; }
        public string Barcode { set; get; }
        public string Description { set; get; }
        public string Status { set; get; }
        public string Label1 { set; get; }
        public string Label2 { set; get; }
        public string Label3 { set; get; }
        public string Label4 { set; get; }
    }
```

I'm actually looking for some advise on weather or not this is the correct way to handle this kind of project (LINQ to XML). Should I be using data sets or some other form or data storage.

I am new to XML and also to relational database type stuff so any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Will

Comment: Why use LINQ to parse XML when XML can already be parsed by XMLReader https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a choice, Iwould thoroughly recommend using `XDocument`(LINQ to XML). It's much simpler to create documents and process them. Personally, my preferred choice in dealing large Xml.

```
var result = doc.Descendants("BAR")
    .Select((e, i)=> new Bars()
            {
                Bar_id = i +1, 
                Brand  = e.Element("BRAN").Value,
                System = e.Element("SYST").Value,
                Code = e.Element("CODE").Value,
                Description = e.Element("DESC").Value,
                Length =e.Element("LEN").Value,
                Status =e.Element("STS").Value,     
                // remaining fileds
                Cuts  = e.Descendants("CUT").Select(c=> new Cuts() 
                                                 {
                                                     Cut_id =  int.Parse(c.Element("NUM").Value),
                                                     Bar_id = i+1,
                                                     AngleL = c.Element("ANGL").Value,
                                                     AngleR = c.Element("ANGR").Value,
                                                     LenInn = c.Element("IL").Value,
                                                     LenOut = c.Element("OL").Value,                                                             
                                                     Barcode = c.Element("BCOD").Value,
                                                     Description = c.Element("DESC").Value,
                                                     Status = c.Element("STAT").Value,
                                                     Label1 = c.Elements("LBL").First().Value,
                                                     Label2 = c.Elements("LBL").Skip(1).First().Value,
                                                     Label3 = c.Elements("LBL").Skip(2).First().Value,
                                                     Label4 = c.Elements("LBL").Skip(3).First().Value,

                                                 }).ToList(),
            }).ToList();
```

Working [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HNIBgx)

Comment: Hi Hari!, Thanks for your response! I like this method because it gives me more control over what I actually keep. There is a lot of information in the file i am parsing that I don't need. How would I modify your code so that every bar in the system ends up with a unique id (bar_id) and each cut gets set with the id of the bar it belongs too? Is there an easy way to do this or should i just use for each loops? The reason for this is I need to create parent child relationships in order to create the tree view. i.e the Bar_id will be the parent of each cut under it...Thanks again!

Comment: @Will updated answer to generate id for each bar and respective cut.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wanted some suggestion here is an easy way of doing it. When it comes to this kind of situations, serialisation is the easiest option. VS has inbuilt functionality to code generate classes for this kind of xml structures.
You can use `Edit > Paste Special` feature for this purpose. So your classes will look like;

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class BODY
{

    private BODYBAR bARField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public BODYBAR BAR
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bARField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bARField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class BODYBAR
{

    private string bRANField;

    private string sYSTField;

    private string cODEField;

    private string dESCField;

    private string dICLField;

    private string dOCLField;

    private ushort lENField;

    private byte sTSField;

    private byte pOSField;

    private byte sVLField;

    private byte iVLField;

    private byte vROTField;

    private byte vU1SField;

    private byte vU1DField;

    private byte vU2SField;

    private byte vU2DField;

    private decimal lENRField;

    private decimal hField;

    private byte mLTField;

    private byte sCPField;

    private byte bRSField;

    private byte iFSField;

    private byte bS1LField;

    private byte bS1RField;

    private byte bS2LField;

    private byte bS2RField;

    private byte eNTHField;

    private BODYBARCUT[] cUTField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string BRAN
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bRANField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bRANField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string SYST
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sYSTField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sYSTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string CODE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cODEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cODEField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DESC
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dESCField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dESCField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DICL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dICLField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dICLField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DOCL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dOCLField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dOCLField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort LEN
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lENField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lENField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte STS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sTSField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sTSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte POS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.pOSField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.pOSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte SVL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sVLField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sVLField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte IVL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.iVLField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.iVLField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte VROT
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vROTField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vROTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte VU1S
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vU1SField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vU1SField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte VU1D
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vU1DField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vU1DField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte VU2S
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vU2SField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vU2SField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte VU2D
    {
        get
        {
            return this.vU2DField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.vU2DField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal LENR
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lENRField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lENRField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal H
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.hField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte MLT
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mLTField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mLTField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte SCP
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sCPField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sCPField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte BRS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bRSField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bRSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte IFS
    {
        get
        {
            return this.iFSField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.iFSField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte BS1L
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bS1LField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bS1LField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte BS1R
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bS1RField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bS1RField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte BS2L
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bS2LField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bS2LField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte BS2R
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bS2RField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bS2RField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte ENTH
    {
        get
        {
            return this.eNTHField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.eNTHField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CUT")]
    public BODYBARCUT[] CUT
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cUTField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cUTField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class BODYBARCUT
{

    private byte nUMField;

    private object tYPEField;

    private byte aNGLField;

    private byte aNGRField;

    private byte aB1Field;

    private byte aB2Field;

    private ushort ilField;

    private decimal olField;

    private string bCODField;

    private object cSNAField;

    private object cSNUField;

    private object tINAField;

    private string dESCField;

    private byte sTATField;

    private string[] lBLField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte NUM
    {
        get
        {
            return this.nUMField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.nUMField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object TYPE
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tYPEField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tYPEField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte ANGL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.aNGLField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.aNGLField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte ANGR
    {
        get
        {
            return this.aNGRField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.aNGRField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte AB1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.aB1Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.aB1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte AB2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.aB2Field;
        }
        set
        {
            this.aB2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ushort IL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ilField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ilField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public decimal OL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.olField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.olField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string BCOD
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bCODField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bCODField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object CSNA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cSNAField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cSNAField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object CSNU
    {
        get
        {
            return this.cSNUField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.cSNUField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public object TINA
    {
        get
        {
            return this.tINAField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.tINAField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string DESC
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dESCField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.dESCField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public byte STAT
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sTATField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sTATField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("LBL")]
    public string[] LBL
    {
        get
        {
            return this.lBLField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.lBLField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can simply deserialise;

```
    BODY objBody = new BODY();
    var xml = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\XMLFile2.xml");
    using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var serialiser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BODY));
        objBody = (BODY)serialiser.Deserialize(reader);
    }
```